# SQL date-format conversion ques

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I need to get my dates to be into the following format:

`12/3/2011` for example as opposed to `12/03/2011`

the SQL I currently use on a result set is:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Created, 105) as Created
```

How can I do this, thanks!

Comment: Is that MM/d/yyyy or dd/M/yyyy?

Comment: Date format 105 is DD/MM/YYYY (Italian style). It follows that the poster wants D/M/Y.

Comment: The question though highlights the problem with using an ambiguous format. For *MOST* audiences, an unambiguous output format is better, e.g. `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, Created), 103)

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard date format in SQL Server that returns a single digit for days or months. You can roll your own using the MONTH, DAY and YEAR functions

```
-- M/D/Y format (USA)
SELECT CAST(MONTH(@date) AS varchar(2)) + '/'
       + CAST(DAY(@date) AS varchar(2)) + '/'
       + CAST(YEAR(@date) AS varchar(4))
```

or

```
-- D/M/Y format (everywhere else)
SELECT CAST(DAY(@date) AS varchar(2)) + '/'
       + CAST(MONTH(@date) AS varchar(2)) + '/'
       + CAST(YEAR(@date) AS varchar(4))
```

Answer (score 1):

All of these approaches can affect performance if this is against a column. Since C# and many other client languages have much more flexible functions for formatting things like dates, you should apply this formatting at the client tier instead. Where, presumably, you'll be looping through all the rows and treating values individually as you display them anyway.

Comment: Keep the data as data. Easier to compare, do math, etc. Formatting strings is definitely a presentation layer function.

Answer (score 0):

Add a REPLACE  '/0'  with '/'  and then check if the LEFT or first character is a 0

Comment: **It's OK to have some words not be bold**

Answer (score 0):

There is a better suggestion.  I would add a format function becuase what you are asking for is a little uncommon,

http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/centurydateformat/

Check out the fnFormatDate.  Then you can format it any way you want, but it may/may not be inline which is what you want to do with the statement

REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Created, 105),'\0','\') as Created