# change the format of the date

Tags: mysql

I have default date from database like '01/02/2015'. 
How can I output date in  '1/2/2015' format?

Comment: Which dbms you are using ?

Comment: Coder of Code : mysql

Comment: You can read the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979050/sql-date-format-conversion-ques)

Comment: @BongaMbombi that's `SQL Server`. Op is asking for the `MySql`.

Comment: @CoderofCode I missed the second comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DATE_FORMAT` function with the formating string as `%c/%e/%Y` to get the format you want.

```
DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%c/%e/%Y')
```

[Here are more formats and information about them](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/).

Comment: Yes i am doing same DATE_FORMAT(a.date,'%d/%m/%Y')

but its output is '01/02/2015'. I need '1/2/2015'. Is is possible using query?

Answer (score 0):

```
select DATE_FORMAT(YOUR_DATE,'%e/%c/%Y') from your_table
```

references : [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)